# Adjusting the open and closed height of Shopify 2.0 Chat Widget

Tags: iframe, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have tried to use CSS to adjust the height of the chat widget based on if it is closed or if it is open. I have used some code someone else has posted here and on the shopify forums however I still can't get it to work as required.

```
  #dummy-chat-button-iframe, #shopify-chat > iframe, #shopify-chat {
    bottom: 65px !important;
    right: 10px !important;
  }

  #shopify-chat > iframe[isOpen="true"], #shopify-chat {
    bottom: 0px !important;
  }
```

It seems the isOpen="true" state isn't being effected.As you can see in the image, the chat widget is still off the screen in the closed state because bottom: 0px !important isn't working.

[Open State Chat Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQnZG.png)

Comment: @Gmacv I saw your solution and hoping you can help me work out why isopen="true" doesn't work for me.